# Facebook API Inconsistencies - Unsupported get request only with some ?ids=<posts.id>

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm really puzzled because I've inconsistent results with two queries.

With the first I'm able to get all the posts of the page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/205309889562612/feed?fields=id%2Cfrom%7Bid%2Cname%7D%2Cmessage%2Ccreated_time%2Ctype%2Clink%2Cname%2Ccomments.summary(true).limit(0)%2Clikes.summary(true).limit(0)
```

In the results I can clearly see a post with id=235109036656557_918476324912628

```
{
      "id": "235109036656557_918476324912628",
      "from": {
        "id": "235109036656557",
        "name": "Fumettologica"
      },
      "message": "La copertina del nuovo numero di Linus, disegnata da Manuele Fior e dedicata a Parigi.",
      "created_time": "2015-11-27T14:37:41+0000",
      "type": "link",
      "link": "http://bit.ly/1NSfOus",
      "name": "La copertina di Linus di dicembre, disegnata da Manuele Fior"
    }
```

But this query (with the same access token):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/235109036656557_918476324912628
```

give this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "D8ZFtKvMUTc"
  }
}
```

At first I thought it could be a permission issue, but the fact that I'm able to get the details with the first query is getting me insane...any idea on how it could be?

Comment: _“Unsupported get request”_ usually means that you don’t have sufficient permission/rights to view an object with the current access token. Now that post is not from the feed owner, but made by someone else on their timeline – so that might be the reason you don’t have the right to request the post details using its full id.

Comment: I would check this [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129719527391638/) and subscribe to it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @Gabriele

Comment: not at all, it seems a persisting bug on FB Graph API actually